# Angular 5 ngSwitch is not working

Tags: angular, navbar, angular5, ng-switch

In my application I am trying to implement navbar based on roles of user. If user is a admin it should show a different menu and for normal user it should show the menu only for the user. I am using ngSwitch to restrict the navbar but could not do it. Please have a look.

```
<div [ngSwitch] = "myrole">
  <ng-template *ngSwitchCase = "'Admin'">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = '/home' routerActive = 'active'>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = '/logout' routerActive = 'active' >Log Out</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" style="text-align:right">
            <span class="nav-link navbar-right">{{username}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template *ngSwitchCase = "'NoUser'">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = '/home' routerActive = 'active'>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = '/login' routerActive = 'active' >Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = '/signup' routerActive = 'active' >Sign UP</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </ng-template>

    </div>
```

Comment: Be consistent with your quoting and spacing. HTML is hard enough to read as it is. Arbitrarily mixing `'` and `"` and inconsistent tag spacing make it hard to read and lead to bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong, Change

**From**

```
 <ng-template *ngSwitchCase = "'Admin'">
```

**To**

```
 <ng-template [ngSwitchCase] = "'Admin'">
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove the `<ng-template>` entirely and instead use the `*` form of a template structural directive on the `<nav>` item like `<nav *ngSwitchCase="'Admin'" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">`. Basically it's EITHER `*` or `<ng-template>`.

Comment: Also tried [ngSwitchCase] inside nav tag. Not working

Answer (score 0):

with ng-template you need to use property binding instead of structural binding. So change
**FROM**

```
<ng-template *ngSwitchCase = "'Admin'">
```

**to**

```
   <ng-template  [ngSwitchCase] = "'Admin'">
```

**OR**
**There is another solution**

use ngSwitchCase as structural directive but without ng-template i.e.

```
<div *ngSwitchCase = "'Admin'">
```

Comment: Hi Can you check the implementation posted in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is code

**HTML template** is

```
<div [ngSwitch] = "myrole">
  <ng-template [ngSwitchCase] = "'Admin'">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" >Log Out</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" style="text-align:right">
            <span class="nav-link navbar-right">{{'Test'}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase] = "'NoUser'">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="/">Home</a>           
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a href="/">Login</a>           
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="/">Sign Up</a>          
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </ng-template>

    </div>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-switch-exampl',
  templateUrl: './switch-exampl.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./switch-exampl.component.css']
})
export class SwitchExamplComponent implements OnInit {

  myrole: string = 'Admin'
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my bad. The role is coming from a service and it is initializing the role as empty string when the component is initialized. So as a solution I have added another section like this

```
 <ng-template  [ngSwitchCase] = "''">......</ng-template>
```

Thanks for your suggestions.